# Accidentally shorted C97 on the Raspberry Pi with a washer

Tags: usb, hardware, electronics, case, troubleshooting

I accidentally dropped a washer and unfortunately it landed on the C97 capacitor. I think that shorted the pi out. The ACT and PWR lights are now solid red and green, whereas it was blinking previously. Is there any hope in saving it? Note to self, always put a case on bare electronics!

Thanks for the help! 
[image]

Comment: I assume you tried powering down the RPi and restarting. Have you tested the c97 capacitor to see if it was damaged?

Answer (score 3):

I had a slightly different problem, but it's related. While tightening a nut next to C97 it popped off. Without C97 the USB ports failed. I replaced the CMT with a 100nf radial capacitor and I'm back in business. CMT in that location was just too hard for me to mount.